# Map2 in elm with lambda

Tags: lambda, elm, anonymous

I would like to change this:

```
add a b =
    a + b


List.map2 add [1,2] [3,4]
```

With something like this:

```
List.map2 (\(a , b ) -> a + b) [1,2] [3,4]
```

Possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the problem you are encountering is that your lambda is defined as accepting a tuple of `(a, b)` rather than two parameters. This is what you want to write (notice the lack of parentheses and comma in the lambda argument):

```
List.map2 (\a b -> a + b) [1,2] [3,4]
```

Since there are two arguments, and `+` takes two arguments, you could take advantage of the ability to make infix operators into regular functions by wrapping them in parentheses (as shown in [the docs](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#applying-functions)), and slim this down by writing it like this:

```
List.map2 (+) [1,2] [3,4]
```